# Java stream parameter limit with no limit (MongoDB inconsistency)

Tags: java, mongodb, java-stream

I have a method which return list of items and takes a limit (used by [`Stream#limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-)) as parameter:

```
public List<Integer> getItems(Long limit) {
    return IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .limit(limit)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How to set the parameter to take all items (with no limit)?

My attempts:

```
    Long limit5 = 5L;
    System.out.println("With limit 5:" + getItems(limit5));
    // works fine: 5 items

    Long noLimitZero = 0L;
    System.out.println("Without limit (zero): " + getItems(noLimitZero));
    // why 0 mean "no items" instead of "all items"

   Long noLimitNegative = -1L;
    System.out.println("Without limit (negative number): " + getItems(noLimitNegative));
    // IllegalArgumentException

    Long noLimitNull = null;
    System.out.println("Without limit (null): " + getItems(noLimitNull));
    // NullPointerException
```

Passing `Long.MAX_VALUE` is not a solution.

#### MongoDB inconsistency

For example MongoDB's [`FindIterable#limit`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html#limit-int-) can take `0` or `null` as no limit.

```
public List<Integer> getItems(Long limit) {
    MongoDatabase mongo = new MongoClient().getDatabase("example");
    MongoCollection<Document> documents = mongo.getCollection("items");
    FindIterable<Document> founded = documents.find();
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Document doc : founded.limit(limit.intValue())) {
        items.add(doc.getInteger("number"));
    }
    return items;
}
```

This inconsistency between methods causes incompatibility, for example one interface with method `List<Integer> getItems(Long limit)` and two implementations: in memory and MongoDB.

Consistency in methods `Stream#skip` and `FindIterable#skip` is preserved.

```
          --------------------------
          | Java       | Mongo     |
------------------------------------
limit = 0 | none items | all items |
------------------------------------
skip = 0  | none skip  | none skip |
------------------------------------
```

#### Refactor method with Stream#limit

I guess there is no way to pass "no limit" parameter to `Stream#limit`, so I must refactor this method to takes "limit" and `0` or `null` or `-1` as "no limit".

```
public static List<Integer> getItems(Long limit) {
    if (limit == null || limit == 0 || limit == -1) {
        return IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        return IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .limit(limit)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public static List<Integer> getItems(Long limit) {
    IntStream items = IntStream.range(1, 10);
    if (limit != null && limit != 0 && limit != -1) {
        items = items.limit(limit);
    }
    return items.boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

There is a better way to achieve consistency between methods `limit`?

Comment: What you have looks fine to me

Comment: Why is "passing `Long.MAX_VALUE` not a solution"?

Comment: Passing `Long.MAX_VALUE` is not a solution because it is only a workaround. In this case (in memory implementation replacement for fetching from database) theoretically is the risk that may be more than `2^63-1` records ;) (but practically it isn't an argument). But I would like to know how to work with Java streams. Java streams in memory can be very long or even infinity (for example `IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)`) and there is may be a case where `Long.MAX_VALUE` is too small.

Comment: Use the last version. When you don’t want a limit, don’t call `limit`, but avoid code duplication. Of course, when the stream source does already support a size (like `IntStream.range`, `Arrays.stream(…)`, `List.subList(…).stream()`, or `Random.ints(…)`), you should prefer specifying the size in the first place. Using `limit`, even with `Long.MAX_VALUE` *has* performance drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

So there's several layers of problems with what you're trying to do.

You say "practicality isn't an argument" and that's fine, but let me just point out that `Long.MAX_VALUE` does exceed the amount of atoms on earth, so the probability that you're getting more entries than that from a database is really small. Not to mention that you go on collecting that data into a list so you might run into memory issues in your own application as well.

So the second thing is that the semantics of `limit()` is that it imposes a fixed limit on the number of entries and "infinity" is not a fixed limit; hence `limit()` just isn't what you're looking for.

Third, you seem to be looking for a way around that so there us a pattern you can use, and that's maintaining your own counter. What you want is something like an `AtomicBigInteger` which doesn't exist in the JDK [but is shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006495/possible-to-safely-increment-biginteger-in-a-thread-safe-way-perhaps-with-atomi).

So what you'd do is create a `Predicate` like this

```
class BelowValue<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    BigInteger limit = BigInteger.ZERO;
    AtomicBigInteger counter = new AtomicBigInteger();

    public BelowValue(BigInteger limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }        
    public BelowValue() {}

    public boolean test(T ignored) {
        // short circuit on zero
        if (BigInteger.ZERO.compareTo(limit) == 0) { return true; }

        // check actual condition
        return  counter.incrementAndGet().compareTo(limit) > 0;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it in your stream with (Java 8)

```
Predicate<T> filter = new BelowValue<>(limit);
return stream
    .filter(filter)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note however that `filter` is *not* a short-circuiting operation, so if you have an infinite stream, this will not terminate (and be very inefficient if your stream is much longer than the limit size).

Java 9's `takeWhile` is short-circuiting, so you can substitute that for `filter` in the above example.

Comment: Don’t do this. The counter may be thread-safe, your assumption that the processing order matches the encounter order is not.

Comment: @Holger I did not assume that.

Comment: Your code does. It will break with a parallel stream, as the counter based predicate allows element to pass based on the order it is evaluated. Which is not the semantic order as a `limit` operation is supposed to let pass the *first* *n* elements in encounter order.